# How to insert order into database and then redirect to Paypal

Tags: php, mysql, button, paypal, e-commerce

Edit:

Let me rephrase my question.. I am trying to insert an order into mysql database before redirecting to paypal.  Right now, I have to do it in two steps.  Press a buttons that will redirect to another page, which stores the order, and then redirect to another page that contains the Paypal Checkout button.

The paypal button is a form itself with hidden inputs. I want to know if there is a way to do it in one step. I.e. when I press the paypal button it will enter my order into mysql database before redirecting to paypal.

Comment: Can you explain one way?

Comment: Sessions?  Database?  Flat file?  XML?  Take your pick.

Comment: not helpful at all. I guess my question is a bit vague. Let me rephase above.

Comment: @GordonM You have really went out of your way to contribute absolutely nothing to this question...

Comment: @KirillFuchs If you'd looked at the edit history you'd have noticed that the original version of the question didn't even mention how the OP was storing the data.  My comment was a sardonic remark on that fact.  I suggest you learn about features such as the question edit history.

Comment: @GordonM Just looked at the edits. My first comment still stands...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can issue a `header()` that updates the `Location:`

```
header('Location: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?' . http_build_query($vars));
```

where `$vars` are all of the necessary variables:

```
    $vars = array(
            'cmd' => '_xclick',
            'business' => $paypal_email,
            'lc' => 'GB',
            'item_name' => $item_name,
            'item_number' => $item_number,
            'amount' => number_format($amount, 2),
            'notify_url' => $notify_url,
            'return' => $return_url,
            'currency_code' => 'USD',
            'button_subtype' => 'goods',
            'no_note' => 0,
            'tax_rate' => 0,
    );
```

This will cause the browser to redirect to PayPal without there being a page load.

Answer (score 0):

In your choose payment page, when submit is click, Save the order in your order table but set the status to 0 or unfinished.  Then, create a another file which can be use for return url in paypal. You can call it confirmation.php. Write a code in there that will update the status to 1 which means payment is successful and now order is ready to be process.

In your paypal connecting script,  set the return url to confirmation.php so that the update status will be perform.

That's pretty much it.